# Is there a option or other solution for quick intervals in WorkManager?

Tags: android, android-service, android-workmanager, android-networking

In my app, I want a **worker** to request my server **every 1 minute** using ( **PeriodicWorkRequest** ) whether there are new messages for the user.

The transmission is therefore kept very small and always contains the same json object that contains the important values. This looks like this:

```
{"1":**7**,"2":**0**,"3":**215**,"4":**0**}
```

In the WorkManager documentation, a minimum period of 15 minutes is specified for the periodic request. but not every app uses "firebase" and still gets all messages directly.
especially the server query is important when the app is closed. Are there any exceptions or other alternatives?

I've been looking for a lot but haven't found a solution so far and hope someone can help me.

Comment: Modern Android has restrictive battery optimizations like [Doze mode](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby). If your app is for consumers, the moment the device is 'sleeping' only Firebase messaging can wake up the device and deliver the message, with a frequency higher the 15 min WorkManager period and subject to [FCM limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#device_throttling).

Comment: Frequent polling of a server is horrible for battery life. Users complained loudly about this, which is why the aforementioned restrictions are in place. "but not every app uses "firebase" and still gets all messages directly" -- and your proof of this is... what?

Comment: Redesign your app.  If you need info that frequently, you should instead push updates from the server.  As a bonus, the server can do it only when needed saving you bandwidth and money.

Comment: You should use push. Or just say to the user battery: "f#*k you!" and go with a permanent service that will keep you alive all the time and you can just use a loop and a Thread.